# How can I run my cloud network alongside Microsoft office online server

Tags: microsoft-office, port, webserver, nextcloud

I am currently running a Nextcloud on my server and it is already using ports 443 and 80. I want to install Office Online Server on the same machine, but currently, I have to run them separately since they both use ports 443 and 80.

Is there a way I could host them both on the same machine?

Comment: Why don’t you change the port on one the services your running locally?

Comment: That would be the office server, and I tried to look for it but Microsoft said these ports couldn't be changed

Answer (score 0):

You can try nginx's stream for triage. Suppose there is web1, and web2 uses port 443 for both. The configuration method is as follows:
nginx.conf configuration file
Add the following code at the end of nginx:

stream {
map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
web1.moeelf.com web1;
web2.moeelf.com web2;
default web;
}

```
log_format stream '$remote_addr [$time_local] [$ssl_preread_server_name] [$upstream] $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time';
access_log /var/log/nginx/stream.log stream;

upstream web1 {
    server web1:65531;
}
upstream web2 {
    server web2:65532;
}
upstream web {
    server nginx:4433;
}
server {
    listen 443 reuseport;
    listen [::]:443 reuseport;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
    ssl_preread on;
}
```

}

Virtual host profiles
Save the following code as an sni.conf file and place it in the virtual host directory. The installation method of nginx is different, and the position of the place will be different. Typically located under /etc/nginx/conf.d/ or /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost/.

server {
listen 65531 ssl http2 reuseport;
server_name web1.moeelf.com;

```
ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/web1.moeelf.com/fullchain.cer;
ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/web1.moeelf.com/web1.moeelf.com.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4:!DH:!DHE;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

#log_format stream '$remote_addr [$time_local] [$ssl_preread_server_name] [$route] $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time';
access_log /var/log/nginx/web1.moeelf.com.log;
```

}
server {
listen 65532 ssl http2 reuseport;
server_name web2.moeelf.com;

```
ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/web2.moeelf.com/fullchain.cer;
ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/web2.moeelf.com/web2.moeelf.com.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4:!DH:!DHE;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

#log_format stream '$remote_addr [$time_local] [$ssl_preread_server_name] [$route] $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time';
access_log /var/log/nginx/web2.moeelf.com.log;
```

}

Please refer to this link for the original article: https://www.moeelf.com/archives/296.html